# Unable to load Stripe's pushPaymentOptionsViewController

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe payments in my iOS app but for some reason, the default Stripe's pushPaymentOptionsVewController to let a user select its payment method is pushed but keeps loading and won't show up. However, the pushShippingViewController works just fine.

I'm using Google cloud functions for my createStripeCustomer and createEphemeralKey functions. I set up my createCustomerKey function in my StripeApi.swift. I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem since it doesn't trigger any error and the code was written following the Stripe documentation.

```
//StripeApi

let StripeApi = _StripeApi()

class _StripeApi: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {

    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {

        let data = [
            "stripe_version": apiVersion,
            "customer_id" : UserService.user.stripeId
        ]

        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createEphemeralKey").call(data) { (result, error) in

            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            guard let key = result?.data as? [String: Any] else {
                completion(nil, nil)
                return
            }

            completion(key, nil)
        }
    }
}




//CheckOutVC

func setupStripeConfig() {
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
        config.createCardSources = true
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
        config.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.postalAddress]

        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeApi)
        paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .default())

        paymentContext.paymentAmount = StripeCart.total
        paymentContext.delegate = self
        paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    }


    @IBAction func payementMethodClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        // vc is pushed but won't stop loading
        paymentContext.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
    }


    @IBAction func shippingMethodClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        // this is working and showing up nicely
        paymentContext.pushShippingViewController()
    }
```

I obviously expect the pushPaymentOptionsViewController to finish loading and show up. But the viewController will just show a blue spinning indicator and a cancel button.

EDIT: Anyone knows if this is a bug in the latest version of Stripe ?

Comment: HI @Enzo Romera I am facing same issue loading indicator so please help me, if your problem is solved.

Thanks 
Tejveer

Answer (score 0):

Your swift code looks fine - what I would suggest is looking at your create ephemeral key cloud function, as these communicate with one another. Ensure you've saved and deployed this before running your swift code.

Let me know how it goes.